# what's the best scenario to use XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am learning xslt, but don't know the best scenarios for use xml + xsl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best scenario to use XSLT is when you need to display XML data in different formats.

I.E., when you have an XML with products, and you need to output them in HTML, TXT, XHTML, WML, you can use XSLT transformations to do that.

The best part of XSLT transformations is that you can do SERVER SIDE transformations, if your client (browser) does not support XSLT natively (like some Mobile Browsers).

Comment: I have an other scenario,
when i need so save interface version in database example for a document manager web  software.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Pablo Santa Cruz' answer, the other common case where you'd want to use XSLT is to manipulate an XML file and get new XML code. For instance, you might use XSLT to change some settings in your web.config before deploying an ASP.NET project.